# What is the best way to call named httpclients in loop without crashing the app?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, signalr, httpclient

Working on building Dashboard which uses 3rd party API endpoint to get data and trying to make this app real-time by using SignalR.

The way I'm trying to achieve this is, I have creacted Named Clients:

```
services.AddHttpClient("SBEnv", client =>
 {
client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Configuration["SBEnvironment:SB_API_URL"]);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", (String)_cache.Get("sb"));
});
```

Which adds token to every request made to this client. I'm calling this client from the controller like this -

```
public async Task<IActionResult> getApps()
{
 var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "apps");
 var response = await _client_SB.SendAsync(request);
 var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
 var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);

 return Ok(result);
}
```

and call hub from client and display result.

Signalr:

As I'm working on API I need to call endpoint every second or even less to make app realtime as much as possible. The basic idea "push only when something changes" behind signalr will not work in this case because of the endpoint. So I have created the hub

```
public class SBHub: Hub
{

}
```

and to call the `named httpclient` I created the `IHostedService` which calls the API every second.

```
internal class SignalRTimedHostedService : IHostedService, IDisposable
{
    private readonly IHubContext<NonProductionHub> _hub;
    private Timer _timer;

    public readonly SBController _SBcontroller;

    public SignalRTimedHostedService(IHubContext<SBHub> hub, SBController SBcontroller)
    {
        _hub = hub;
        _SBcontroller = SBcontroller;
    }

    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {

        _timer = new Timer(DoWork, null, TimeSpan.Zero, 
            TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private void DoWork(object state)
    {
        var result = _SBcontroller.getApps();
        _hub.Clients.All.SendAsync("TestBrodcasting", result);
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {

        _timer?.Change(Timeout.Infinite, 0);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _timer?.Dispose();
    }
}
```

The problem is whenever `IHostedService` runs it returns the first request but for subsequent requests, it is returning following info and hub gets disconnected displayed in firefox console.

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
      Request finished in 9632.0481ms 101
info: System.Net.Http.HttpClient.SBEnv.LogicalHandler[100]
      Start processing HTTP request GET https://api.domain.io/apps
info: System.Net.Http.HttpClient.SBEnv.ClientHandler[100]
      Sending HTTP request GET https://api.domain.io/apps
info: System.Net.Http.HttpClient.SBEnv.ClientHandler[101]
      Received HTTP response after 40.6678ms - Unauthorized
```

and showing

```
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.HubConnectionContext[6]
      Failed writing message. Aborting connection.
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Self referencing loop detected for property 'task' with type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1+AsyncStateMachineBox`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IActionResult,TestApp.Controllers.SBController+<getApps>d__2]'. Path 'arguments[0].stateMachine.<>t__builder'.
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.CheckForCircularReference(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonProperty property, JsonContract contract, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.CalculatePropertyValues(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContainerContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonProperty property, JsonContract& memberContract, Object& memberValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.Serialize(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.SerializeInternal(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Protocol.JsonHubProtocol.WriteArguments(Object[] arguments, JsonTextWriter writer)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Protocol.JsonHubProtocol.WriteInvocationMessage(InvocationMessage message, JsonTextWriter writer)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Protocol.JsonHubProtocol.WriteMessageCore(HubMessage message, IBufferWriter`1 stream)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Protocol.JsonHubProtocol.WriteMessage(HubMessage message, IBufferWriter`1 output)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Protocol.HubProtocolExtensions.GetMessageBytes(IHubProtocol hubProtocol, HubMessage message)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Protocol.JsonHubProtocol.GetMessageBytes(HubMessage message)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.SerializedHubMessage.GetSerializedMessage(IHubProtocol protocol)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.HubConnectionContext.WriteCore(SerializedHubMessage message)
```

To which I have tried to ignore it by adding -

```
services.AddMvc()
 .AddJsonOptions(
  options => options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
  );
```

But it's still showing me the same error, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

How do I make this working? what I'm missing?

I'm very new to .net please don't FLIP on me.

Comment: can you post full stack trace of the exception?

Comment: @AlexandrMihalciuc I have updated the question.

Comment: Don't try and serialize a `Task`, serialize the result of the `Task`.  Most likely you'll want to make `DoWork` async by doing `var result = await _SBcontroller.getApps();` or leave it synchronous (and open to deadlocks) by doing `var result = _SBcontroller.getApps().Result;`

Comment: @Matthew awesome that woked for JSON error but I'm still getting Unauthorized error, I'm storing my token in the cache then it attaches to every request for the named client. It is working if I do a single request by using named client but it faile if I run it as a service, any thoughts on that?

Comment: Are you sure your bearer token is correct?

Comment: I drilled down the problem, I'm using `IHostedService` to get token and there is service which I mentioned in my question. The service in my questions runs before the service which gets token and because of that Httpclient has no token and that's the reason I'm getting that error, is there any way to workaround to this?